# SQL query to find EmployeeName, Manager Name from a table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables as follows

`EmployeeTable`:

[image]

`Employe_Manger`:

[image]

Note that `E1` is manager for `E2`, `E3` and `E4` are managers for `E5`.

Now find a query to find out the manager name and employee name side by side.

i.e. result should be

[image]

Comment: And what does the manager table look like?

Comment: @Luka I suspect the manager id references employeetable too, not a separate manager table.

Comment: @Luka: There is no manager table, As the manager is also an employee even his details are in EmployeeTable only.

Comment: @MitchWheat: I tried some inner join sql query but was not correct, so I have not posted it.

Comment: @ismailbaig: It would be great if you showed your solution despite it being incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT one.EmployeeName AS "Employee", two.EmployeeName AS "Manager"
FROM Employee AS one
INNER JOIN Employee_Manager AS temp ON one.EmployeeId = temp.EmployeeId
INNER JOIN Employee AS two ON temp.ManagerId = two.EmployeeId
```

Is it what you want to achieve?